# ExpandEnvironmentStrings Not Expanding My Variables

Tags: c++, winapi, environment-variables

I have a process under the Run key in the registry. It is trying to access an environment variable that I have defined in a previous session. I'm using ExpandEnvironmentStrings to expand the variable within a path. The environment variable is a user profile variable. When I run my process on the command line it does not expand as well. If I call 'set' I can see the variable.

Some code...

```
CString strPath = "\\\\server\\%share%"
TCHAR cOutputPath[32000]; 
DWORD result = ExpandEnvironmentStrings((LPSTR)&strPath, (LPSTR)&cOutputPath,  _tcslen(strPath) + 1);
 if ( !result )
 {
  int lastError = GetLastError();
  pLog->Log(_T( "Failed to expand environment strings. GetLastError=%d"),1, lastError);
 }
```

When debugging Output path is exactly the same as Path. No error code is returned.

What is goin on?

Comment: I guess that `strPath == Path` and `cOutputPath == OutputPath`, but a bit of sanitization would help.

Comment: Please post valid code.  You define variable `strPath` and `cOutputPath` and then use variables `Path` and `OutputPath`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One problem is that you are providing the wrong parameters to `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` and then using a cast to hide that fact (although you do need a cast to get the correct type out of a `CString`).

You are also using the wrong value for the last parameter.  That should be the size of the output buffer, not the size of the input length (from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265%28VS.85%29.aspx) `the maximum number of characters that can be stored in the buffer pointed to by the lpDst parameter`)

Putting that altogether, you want:

```
ExpandEnvironmentStrings((LPCTSTR)strPath,
                         cOutputPath,
                         sizeof(cOuputPath) / sizeof(*cOutputPath));
```

Comment: Right on the head. Thanks. I just need to take my time with this C++ business... .Net has made me lazy...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any error checking code in your snippet, you don't assert the return value.  If there's a problem, you'd never discover it.  Also, you are using ANSI strings, beware of the [weirdo requirement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265%28VS.85%29.aspx) for the nSize argument (1 extra).

Comment: I updated to post to better reflect my code. And I did notice that strange requirement for the ANSI. The function does not return an error. :\ Just seems to do nothing at all!

Comment: @Adam: that didn't help much.  How are strPath and Path related?  Why are you casting?  Casting is bad.

Comment: Sorry update the code. I was casting because the compiler was complaining...great idea right?

Answer (score 1):

What about `buffersize` ? Is it initialized - to the right value ?

The documentation states that `If the destination buffer is too small to hold the expanded string, the return value is the required buffer size, in characters.`