# How to make the 'fstream' make files in a custom directory

Tags: c++

So I want to make my program create a file and read/write in that file in a custom directory, preferably in the %appdata% (C:\users\< name >\appdata\roaming)

How do I do this?

I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

fstream inFile("/myFolder/myFile.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);


return 0;

}
```

But how do I get it in the %appdata% folder?
Do I use the 'system()' function?

For an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

fstream inFile("/myFolder/myFile.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
system("MOVE C:\\myFolder %appdata%");


return 0;

}
```

Like. . . you know, this works but I feel like there's a more efficient way/better way. Also I feel like sometimes on some different computers, the 'system()' function might cause a bug. . .

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2404103/560648

Comment: An arguably better dupe is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964124/how-to-get-the-appdata-folder-in-c

Comment: @n.m. Dunno, then you have to concat the result to "myFile.txt". OP wants to form a path that _includes_ a magic subtree. `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` literally gets you precisely there, being designed for this purpose, and the intent of both questions I think matches that.